# Could anyone scrape an element with Jsoup?

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape [this link](https://s5.sir.sportradar.com/betsgi/en/1/season/42556/team/2817) using Jsoup with Kotlin/Java. And I have problem in scrapping players part (under Current Squad). Could anyone parse it?

Comment: You should add what you tried and what specific problem you're having.

Comment: I just asked for someone to scrape that part of the page. The problem is that it seems there is nothing. when i parse that element it returns nothing :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access the information directly using only the response from that link.
You can make a JSON object with the http response from https://stats.fn.sportradar.com/betsgi/en/America:Argentina:Buenos_Aires/gismo/stats_team_squad/2817 and https://stats.fn.sportradar.com/betsgi/en/America:Argentina:Buenos_Aires/gismo/stats_teamplayer_facts/2817/42556.

As an example in python you can get the minutes played by each player as follows:

```
import urllib
import json

f=urllib.urlopen('https://stats.fn.sportradar.com/betsgi/en/America:Argentina:Buenos_Aires/gismo/stats_team_squad/2817')
f2=urllib.urlopen('https://stats.fn.sportradar.com/betsgi/en/America:Argentina:Buenos_Aires/gismo/stats_teamplayer_facts/2817/42556')
j=json.loads(f.read())
j2=json.loads(f2.read())


plrs=j['doc'][0]['data']['players']
for plr in plrs:
    print '========================='
    print plr['name']
    try:
        print 'minutes played:' +str(j2['doc'][0]['data'][str(plr['_id'])]['stats']['total']['minutes_played'])
    except KeyError, e:
        pass
```

Comment: Could you explain that how did you find those links?